# How to download image from ip camera in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ip-camera, onvif

When I send http request to Ip camera (Onvif)

```html
    "<GetSnapshotUri xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl\">" +
          "<ProfileToken>PROFILE_000</ProfileToken></GetSnapshotUri>";
```

I got Response containing Url:

```html
....
 <s:Body><trt:GetSnapshotUriResponse><trt:MediaUri> 
 <tt:Uri>http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi</tt:Uri> 
 <tt:InvalidAfterConnect>false</tt:InvalidAfterConnect> 
 <tt:InvalidAfterReboot>false</tt:InvalidAfterReboot><tt:Timeout>PT5S</tt:Timeout></trt:MediaUri> 
 </trt:GetSnapshotUriResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I've tried to use [image_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader) plugin, not worked.
  I can see it in browser(Chrome) but I can't view it via Image.network('http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi') Widget

I got error

```html
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 401, http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
#2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I've found answer on Java

```html
URL url = new URL("http://webacm-ip-adr:8084/snapshot.cgi");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
String jpg = "sample.jpg";
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(jpg);
IOUtils.copy(input, output);
```

Updated after get correct answer. I can see params needed for create Digest key, but due I can't return Response object by dart code
[Response header in http sniffer that I can't get by Dart code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAaCH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead of image downloader use

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
 Future<File> _downloadFile(String authEncoded,String url, String param) async {
  final response = await http.post(url,
    headers: {
       HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic ' + authEncoded 
       // Do same with your authentication requirement
    },
    body: param,
  );

 response.headers.forEach((k,v) => print (k+" : "+v));
 //Your response headers here

if(response.statusCode==200){
 String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File file = new File('$dir/image.jpg');
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  return file;
 } else {
    print("Error : " + response.statusCode.toString());
  }
}
```

Now Call

```
File file = await _downloadFile("http://192.168.1.102:13237/snapshot.cgi", "<GetSnapshotUri xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl\"><ProfileToken>PROFILE_000</ProfileToken></GetSnapshotUri>");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I get error: Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'image.jpg' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: GoAhead-Webs
Date: Thu Dec 26 05:51:48 2019
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="goAhead", domain=":31122",qop="auth", nonce="cdb3f5e3d9fe4fc5768726b5920f97ba", opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41",algorithm="MD5", stale="FALSE"
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html

<html><head><title>Document Error: Unauthorized</title></head>
  <body><h2>Access Error: Unauthorized</h2>
  <p>Access to this document requires a User ID</p></body></html>

Comment: is there any requirement of basic auth to access the url?

Comment: Your answer is correct, I just need to pass one more auth step for getting snapshot

Comment: Could you give me a hint what is easiest way to pass digest auth on Dart. include params like realm, nonce and etc

Comment: How can I get header of response for extract params for digest generate?          final response = await http.post(url,
    headers: {
    },
    body: param,
  );                                                                                                                                      after that code I get nothing by expression                                            print(response.headers);

Comment: i have set an example for basic auth similarly you can set digest in header

Comment: Yes understand that. Why I can't return Response object when I do request to this url = http://192.168.88.32:31122/snapshot.cgi. I only see realm, nonce and etc in http sniffer. When I do request to url = http://192.168.88.32:10080. There's no problem to get Response object

Comment: Really cant help beyond this as don't know your exact setup and what request response are being played. Try to debug headers, responses, etc by printing them.

Comment: There is a Response object in your code. So Ip camera Response with 401 code Unauthorized (I've added screenshot of sniffer at the end of Question), but Why I can't get this error from Response object in your code? I can't print nothing from Response object

Comment: also added values of response headers

Comment: Could you try to help with my next authentification problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491178/flutter-app-connect-to-ip-camera-with-digest-auth